# AWS: DMS: difference between resume and restart

Tags: aws-dms

I am using AWS DMS to sync data between my RDS table and Redshift Table

When to use what I am confused.

Can someone explain it based on their experience.

Example: I stopped the DMS. Then I wanted to start the DMS from start, that is start by Truncate all the data in the existing table.

in the above case, i modify the task, select truncate option and save. Now what to select resume or restart.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in this [post](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/dms-restart-resume-failed-task):

> Resume - When you resume a task, AWS DMS continues replication from
> the last point before the task stopped or failed. Restart - When you
> restart a task, AWS DMS begins replication from the start, and uses
> the table preparation mode that you chose when you created the task.

If you want to truncate all data and load data from scratch, then you would have to use "restart" option.

**Note:**  In this case, your DMS task has to be configured with full load task setting `"TargetTablePrepMode": "TRUNCATE_BEFORE_LOAD"`